# How to pass JToggleButton to another class?

Tags: java, awt, togglebutton

I wanted to pass pressed `toggleButton` into another class but failed to do so.

**Activity A**

```
  confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    boolean buttonClicked = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                        if (ButtonList[i].isSelected()) { // if toggleButton is clicked
                            buttonClicked = true;
                            fillInDetails details= new fillInDetails(title,day,time,ButtonList[i]); // pass toggleButton to another class
                            details.setVisible(true);
                            setVisible(false);
                            frame.dispose();
                        }
                    }
                    if (!buttonClicked) {
                        JFrame parent= new JFrame();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(parent, "You haven't select a seat");
                    }
                }

            });
```

**fillInDetails**

```
public class fillInDetails extends JPanel{

     static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fill in Details");

     public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                createAndShowGui();
            });
        }

     static void createAndShowGui() {
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(new fillInDetails("","","","")); //Error here 
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }


    public fillInDetails(String title, String day, String time, JToggleButton buttonList) {

    }

}
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The constructor fillInDetails(String, String, String, String) is undefined

    at gui.fillInDetails.createAndShowGui(fillInDetails.java:20)
    at gui.fillInDetails.lambda$0(fillInDetails.java:14)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: "The constructor fillInDetails(String, String, String, String) is undefined"
You have to pass 3 Strings and a JToggleButton and not 4 Strings.
I suggest you to just pass null or an empty JToggleButton and do a null check

Comment: null / new JToggleButton();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`frame.getContentPane().add(new fillInDetails("","","","")`

As ScriptKiddy and your error said, the constructor `fillInDetails(String, String, String, String)` is undefined.

Yours is `fillInDetails(String title, String day, String time, JToggleButton buttonList)`